# react native and parse, currentuser is null after login and cmd+R

Tags: parse-platform, reactjs, react-native

I'm having a problem with React Native and Parse JS SDK.

 And I'm using [ParseReact](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact)

I have built a login, sign up and a main view, Sign up and log in works well but after i logged in -> directed to main view and when I refresh the app (CMD+R) in my simulator, it brings me back to the login view again, i should be brought to Main view.

As you can see I have set a state for initialComponent:

```
this.state = {        
      InitialComponent : ((!currentUser) ? LoginView : MainView)
};
```

This allows my navigator to check for currentUser is null then load LoginView as initial component, else set Main View(user logged in)

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var MainView = require('./MainView');
var LoginView = require('./LoginView');


var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');
Parse.initialize("mykey", "mykey");


var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navigator,
  Component
} = React;


class MyApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
      console.log('Current User:' + currentUser);

      this.state = {        
        InitialComponent : ((!currentUser) ? LoginView : MainView)
      };
    }

   render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
              initialRoute={{
                 name : 'StatusList',
                 component: this.state.InitialComponent
              }}
              configureScene = {() =>{
                return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
              }}
              renderScene={(route, navigator) =>{
                if(route.component) {
                  return React.createElement(route.component, {navigator});
                }
              }}/>

        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', function() { return MyApp });
```

In my Xcode console, i kept getting current user is null after each refresh even though i have previously logged in. On my parse app, I can see new session has been created.

In my LoginView.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var SignUp = require('./SignUp');
var MainView = require('./MainView');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Navigator,
  AlertIOS,
  Component
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 15,
      marginTop: 30,
      backgroundColor: '#0179D5',
   },
  text: {
    color: '#000000',
    fontSize: 30,
    margin: 100
  },

  headingText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: '100',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginBottom: 20,
    letterSpacing: 3
  },

  textBox: {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: '#4BB0FC',
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    padding:10,
    height:40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 15,
  },

  greenBtn: {
    height: 36,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#2EA927',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },

  signUpButton: {
    marginTop: 10,
    height: 36,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#FF5500',
    justifyContent: 'center'

  },

  btnText: {
    color : '#fff',
    fontSize: 15,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },

  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },

   loginForm : {
      flex:1,
      marginTop:100
   }
});

class LoginView extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
      };

    }

    checkLogin() {
        var success = true;
        var state = this.state;
        for(var key in state){
          if(state[key].length <= 0){
            success = false;
          }
        }

        if(success) {
          this._doLogin();
        } else {
          //show alert
          AlertIOS.alert('Error','Please complete all fields',
            [{text: 'Okay', onPress: () => console.log('')}]
          );
        }
    }

    goMainView() {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        title: "Home",
        component: MainView
      });
    }

    goSignUp() {
      this.props.navigator.push({
        title: "Sign Up",
        component: SignUp
      });
    }

    _doLogin() {
      var parent = this;
      Parse.User.logIn(this.state.username, this.state.password, {
        success: function(user) {
            parent.goMainView();
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
          AlertIOS.alert('Login Error', error.message,
            [{text: 'Okay', onPress: () => console.log('')}]
          );
        }
      });
    }

    onUsernameChanged(event) {
      this.setState({ username : event.nativeEvent.text });
    }

    onPasswordChanged(event) {
      this.setState({ password : event.nativeEvent.text });
    }

    render() {
       return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.loginForm}>
                <Text style={styles.headingText}>
                  MyStatus
                </Text>

               <TextInput style={styles.textBox}
                placeholder='Username'
                onChange={this.onUsernameChanged.bind(this)}
                placeholderTextColor='#fff'
                autoCorrect={false}
               >
               </TextInput>

               <TextInput style={styles.textBox}
                placeholder='Password'
                onChange={this.onPasswordChanged.bind(this)}
                placeholderTextColor='#fff'
                password={true}
               >
               </TextInput>

               <TouchableHighlight style={styles.greenBtn}
                  underlayColor='#33B02C'
                  onPress={this.checkLogin.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Login</Text>

                </TouchableHighlight>


                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.signUpButton}
                  underlayColor='#D54700'
                  onPress={this.goSignUp.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style={styles.btnText}>Sign Up</Text>

                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

          </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = LoginView;
```

Am I doing it the wrong way? Kindly advice. Or is it something wrong with parse localstorage/session?

Comment: Have you tried put the `constructor` code into `getInitialState`?

Comment: @skyline75489 Hi yes, i have tried changing to React.createClass with a getinitialstate, its still returns currentuser as null even i have logged in before refresh. Is my way of doing this correct, in terms of checking for currentuser

Comment: Where is your login code?

Comment: @skyline75489 just added it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because React Native only provides asynchronous storage, we're forced to make `Parse.User.current()` an asynchronous call that returns a Promise. Since you're already using `Parse+React`, it's really easy to handle this. Your component that changes based upon whether the user is logged in or not (MyApp) should subscribe to `ParseReact.currentUser`. This stays synchronized with the current user, and allows your component to automatically update the moment the user logs in or out. For a demo of this, look at the *AnyBudget* [**demo**](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact/blob/master/demos/AnyBudget/js/LoginWrapper.react.js) in the GitHub repo:

Comment: ah I see thats why, thank you. Btw how do I get the username using `ParseReact.currentUser`

Comment: Hi, i have tried it out, i added the mixins and observe method to my index js. It still returns null when i check for this.data.user(even after i have logged in).

Comment: very weird, i tried the method you shown me, in my index, before render, i check for this.data.user , if its null then set my initialComponent to login if not to the MainView. It didnt work out, so i tried checking the this.data.user with console.log(), weird thing, it logs twice, one with a null and then with the user data. I only wrote console.log() once, but it logs twice. not sure what's up so i thought you may have a clue.

Comment: its alright now, it seems the bug was caused by my code logic, fixed it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

In react-native...

```
import Parse from 'parse/react-native';

Parse.User.currentAsync()
.then((currentUser)=>{
    if (currentUser) {
        Alert.alert('', JSON.stringify(currentUser))
    }
});
```

Comment: VERY HELPFUL. the error message returned from the parse js sdk code says use `currentUserAsync` and it doesn't work. Changing to `currentAsync` works!

Answer (score 0):

At first in my case I use ParseReact.Mutation that work perfectly.
After that I got a requirement that some field need to be unique, so I use `Parse.Cloud` to solve problem.

```
// For normally situaltion is work fine.
ParseReact.Mutation.Set(this.data.myObject, {
  normal_field: this.state.value
}).dispatch();

// But if I use Parse.Cloud. Is there any solution to sync data to ParseReact.currentUser?
Parse.Cloud.run('setUniqueField', {
  userID: this.data.user.id.objectId,
  uniqueField: this.state.value,
}, {
  success: function (response) {
    // It doesn't work!
    // ParseReact.currentUser.update();
    this.props.navigator.pop();
  }.bind(this),
  error: function (error) {
    console.log('[Parse Cloud Error]: ', error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew's solution (alone) didn't work for me.  In case anyone else is stuck, here's what was happening: subscribing to `Parse.User.current()` didn't work, and `this.data.user` was always null.

To fix this, I had to change:

`var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
var ParseReact = require('parse-react');`

to

`var Parse = require('parse/react-native').Parse;
var ParseReact = require('parse-react/react-native');`

then everything started working beautifully.  It was loading the `browser` version of the parse modules until I forced it to load the `react-native` versions.